# Angular 2 reload data on Post

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to refresh my array of data from the server after a user submits a reactive form and I post to the server using an api.

I've seen two methods of achieving this.

**Method 1** - Refresh interval.

app.component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllProjects();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.getAllProjects();
    }, 3000);
}

getAllProjects() {
    this.dataService.getProjects().subscribe(
        data => { this.pages = data },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log(this.pages)
    );
}

onSubmitProject() {
    this.newProject.CourseId = this.addProjectForm.value.CourseId;
    this.newProject.TypeId = this.addProjectForm.value.TypeId;
    this.newProject.SignOff = this.addProjectForm.value.SignOff;
    this.newProject.StartDateTime = this.addProjectForm.value.StartDateTime;

    this.dataService.storePage(this.newProject)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
}
```

dataService.ts

```
getProjects() {
    return this.http.get("/api/project/getallprojects");
}

storePage(project: Project) {
    return this.http.post('/api/Project/postproject', project);
}
```

This functionally works for me, however I don't have a need to refresh every x seconds. This seems inefficient for my needs.

Method 2 - use something like:

```
this.projects.push(project);
```

This doesn't work for me because the data needs to include the id assigned to each object which is assigned by the database. Therefore I need to make a call to the server and re-fetch the data.

Even though method 1 functionally works, the following (this.getAllProjects()) does not:

```
onSubmitProject() {
    this.newProject.CourseId = this.addProjectForm.value.CourseId;
    this.newProject.TypeId = this.addProjectForm.value.TypeId;
    this.newProject.SignOff = this.addProjectForm.value.SignOff;
    this.newProject.StartDateTime = this.addProjectForm.value.StartDateTime;

    this.dataService.storePage(this.newProject)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => console.log(response),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
    this.getAllProjects();
    console.log(this.pages);
}
```

If I remove the refresh interval from method 1 and I add this.getAllProjects(); and console.log() to the submit method. The data does not update. the console log shows the same data, however if I manually refresh the page I get the data.

What's the correct/best way to refresh data from the GET api call after a POST?

Comment: `this.getAllProjects();` should be inside when you call `storePage` since these calls are asynchronous in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have written, your `getAllProjects` method is called before completing `storePage` since these calls are asynchronous in nature, you have to call `getAllProjects` once your `storePage` is complete which is inside its subscribe.

```
onSubmitProject() {
    this.newProject.CourseId = this.addProjectForm.value.CourseId;
    this.newProject.TypeId = this.addProjectForm.value.TypeId;
    this.newProject.SignOff = this.addProjectForm.value.SignOff;
    this.newProject.StartDateTime = this.addProjectForm.value.StartDateTime;

    this.dataService.storePage(this.newProject)
        .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.getAllProjects();
                }
        );        
    console.log(this.pages);
}
```